# 2つあるHTML機能を一つにまとめたいです。

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

失礼致します。

今それぞれ違う機能をもったHTMLファイル（JS機能含む）があります。
一つはサジェスト機能し検索することができます。2つ目はURL先で表示されているデータをテーブルに変換して表示する機能です。この二つを組み合わせていただけないでしょうか？
前者は検索してページを表示してもJSON形式のため見づらい
後者はテーブルに変換して見やすいがURL先をあらかじめ指定するため応用が利かない。
最終的に検索してテーブル表示させたいです。
画面遷移してもしなくても大丈夫です。

難しい部類に入るかと思いますがJavaScriptに詳しいかた何卒宜しく御願い致します。
初心者のため質問内容で分からない点があるかと思います。修正しますので遠慮なくおっしゃて下さい。

---HTML---

```
<body>
<form method="get"action="http://localhost:8180/api/stock/search?q=" Accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="text"  id="ac2"  name="car_name" >
<input type="submit" value="検索"></form>

</body>
```

--javascript--

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#ac2").autocomplete({
        source: function(req, resp){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8180/api/stockcars/keyword",
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    car_name : req.term
                },
                success: function(o){
                    resp(o);
                },
                error: function(xhr, ts, err){
                    resp(['']);
                }
          });

        }
    });
});
```

---JSON形式のデータをテーブルにするHTMLファイル---

```
     //画面構築完了後URL先を指定したらそのJSON形式のテーブルを表示する。
    $(function() {
        $("").ready(function(){
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'http://localhost:8180/api/stockcars/search?q=',
              dataType: 'json',
              jsonCallback: 'data',
              success: function(json){
                var rows = "";

                     $.each(json, function(i, item){


                        $.each(item,function(key,value){
                        rows += "<tr>";
                        rows += "<td>";
                        rows += key;
                        rows += "</td>";
                        rows += "<td>";
                        rows += value;
                        rows += "</td>";
                        });

                    });
                    //テーブルに作成したhtmlを追加する
                    $("#tbl").append(rows);
              }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tbl" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>項目</th><th>名前</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: http://localhost:8180/api/stockcars/search?q= にテーブルを作成して、返れば良いでしょうか。
でも、現在の構造は良いじゃないですか。

Comment: Yang Wenxuan様

ありがとうございます。
そのURL先はJSON表記でいじることなくJSなど駆使して可視化するだけにしたいんです。

Comment: take様
編集していただいてありがとうございます。
プロだとここまで見やすくできるんですね。

Comment: *この二つを組み合わせていただけないでしょうか？* では「質問」ではなくて「依頼」になっていると思います。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 質問ではなく依頼である、SOは質問 & 回答のサイトである。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery使用時に以下の書き方をすると、どれを使ってもDOM構築後のタイミングで実行したい処理を実行できます。

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/*実行したい処理*/
});

$().ready(function(){
/*実行したい処理*/
});

$(function(){
/*実行したい処理*/
});
```

よって、下記のように変更すれば、解決できると思います。

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#ac2").autocomplete({
        source: function(req, resp){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8180/api/stockcars/keyword",
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    car_name : req.term
                },
                success: function(o){
                    resp(o);
                },
                error: function(xhr, ts, err){
                    resp(['']);
                }
          });

        }
    });

    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:8180/api/stockcars/search?q=',
          dataType: 'json',
          jsonCallback: 'data',
          success: function(json){
            var rows = "";

                 $.each(json, function(i, item){


                    $.each(item,function(key,value){
                    rows += "<tr>";
                    rows += "<td>";
                    rows += key;
                    rows += "</td>";
                    rows += "<td>";
                    rows += value;
                    rows += "</td>";
                    });

                });
                //テーブルに作成したhtmlを追加する
                $("#tbl").append(rows);
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yang Wenxuan様
ありがとうございます。
試させていただいたところ遷移先はJSONのままでした。
ただこれといったエラーは起きなかったのでこれに何か加えればできますかね？
もしくは画面遷移しないようにすれば反映できるかもしれません。
難しい質問なのにお答えいただいてありがとうございます。